What species of spider is this, living in India?

Found in India during summers in not humid, just very hot weather.
Please tell me what species it is, what it eats and how to care for it?

Please [edit] to include location, size, and other useful info.

We can deduce from the abdomen pattern that it is a Housefly Catcher of the genus Plexippus
The location further aids in narrowing down the exact species as their is only one spider in the area that is of the genus Plexippus. And that is the Pantropical Jumping Spider (Plexippus paykulli).

Plexippus paykulli is a species of jumping spider. It is native to south east Asia but has spread to other parts of the world and globe. In the United States it is called the pantropical jumping spider. It is usually associated with buildings and may be found near light sources catching insects attracted by the light. It is named in honor of Gustaf von Paykull. Source: https://wikipedia.org


Image reference: https://www.inaturalist.org/photos/294156075, Photo 294156075, (c) John Sim, some rights reserved (CC BY-NC), uploaded by John Sim
